# Actionscript 3: Healthbar and Button

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, layer, movieclip

So basically I am making a game in which a button is clicked to decrease the amount of health in a healthbar. I have a button on the stage named fortyfivedown_btn, and a healthbar, which is a 101 frame (includes zero) movieclip. The health bar has an instance name of lifebar. On the stage, the button coding is:

```
fortyfivedown_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fortyfivedownClick);
function fortyfivedownClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    lifebar.health = lifebar.health-45;
    }
```

Inside the healthbar movieclip, I have a layer of coding that is:

```
var health:int = 100;
gotoAndStop(health + 1);
if(health < 0) health = 0;
else if(health > 100) health = 100;
gotoAndStop(health + 1);
```

So, there is my coding. The thing is, when the button is clicked, the healthbar does not go down. I traced the health variable in the button:

```
  fortyfivedown_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fortyfivedownClick);
  function fortyfivedownClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
        lifebar.health = lifebar.health-45;
        }
        {
                trace(lifebar.health);  
                }
```

I saw that the output is 0. For some reason the button believes the health is 0, when I declared it was 100 inside the healthbar movieclip? Any help is appreciated.

(Edit)

Alright, in answer to the trace question, if I don't do it like that, there is no output. I should say I'm a beginner at this all, and am learning as I go, so please bear with me. Here is my fla file:

https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=9AB08B59DCCDF9C6&resid=9AB08B59DCCDF9C6%21107&authkey=AGqFHhlHnvOXvuc

Comment: your code is very confusing, why do you have extra braces around the trace outside of a function? I think you're not understanding how code in the timeline works, that is only triggered when the frame is entered.  You need health to be a variable that is in a Class associated with your MovieClip instead of on the timeline.  Ideally I would use a setter method to adjust the frame it goes to in the MovieClip using the logic you show basically.  Posting your FLA will help.

Comment: just added my answer (also had some formatting issues a second ago there) should be good now, let me know if there's problems but I tried it out locally and works out fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so take the code that was in your lifebar movie clip out entirely, you can just delete that layer for now, then replace the code you have in the main scene with this and you should get the result you want:

```
fortyfivedown_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fortyfivedownClick);

var health:int = 100;

lifebar.gotoAndStop(101);

function fortyfivedownClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    health -= 45;

    if(health < 0) health = 0;
    else if(health > 100) health = 100;

    lifebar.gotoAndStop(health + 1);

    //Can write this also: lifebar.health += 45;
    trace(health);
}
```

there's other ways to go about doing this but given your current setup this is going to be the least modification to get what you want.  Another option is setting the width on a sprite.

I uploaded a modified fla and companion as file for how I would personally go about doing this instead of including things on the timeline so much:

http://www.mediafire.com/?d38hbm32p71x1n8

Comment: No problem I actually have a solution I like better going to post it on media fire real quick here.  This one I'm using a class that defines the healthbar property using a getter and setter, the fla and as need to be in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks you so much, you went above and beyond! I'll check it out, and probably do that instead.